# Ubuntu 18.10 Can't connect an Xbox controller via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, 18.10, gamepad, bluez

Recently, I've been unable to connect my Xbox One S gamepad via bluetooth. In the past, I had to delete (unpair) and then pair the gamepad again in order to get it to connect, but lately it doesn't pair at all. It shows the spinning circle, bluetooth connected icon appears for a moment in the top bar, the bluetooth settings say connected and then after a second it switches to disconnected. The connection light on the gamepad never stops blinking, meaning that the gamepad doesn't consider itself connected at any point in the process.

I've been trying various kernel versions, but could only manage to get it to work on 4.18.0-10-generic once. After reboot it switched back to being unable to pair. I am using the xpad-neo driver in case that's relevant, but I think it's a bluetooth issue.

dmesg output:

```
[   60.585791] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   60.585809] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   60.585809] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   60.585813] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   60.585814] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   60.585819] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   60.592516] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   60.737100] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   60.737102] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   60.737105] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   60.808273] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   60.808284] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   60.808292] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   71.876175] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   89.961169] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  105.958137] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  136.962242] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

It prints a new "hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)" line every time I retry the re-pairing process.

Comment: Try running `sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm` and then connecting the controller. The xpad driver is irrelevant for Bluetooth. It's only for controllers on USB or using the MS wireless adapter. Bluetooth is via standard HCI.

Comment: @dobey xpad neo is not the same as xpad and is specifically made for XBONE S bluetooth pads. It is supposed to be disabling ertm as part of the driver, but when I checked, it was set to false and when I manually edited it and rebooted, it was set to false again. This might be the cause here.

Comment: I'm on 18.04 with the same controller, and it works fine with stock Ubuntu kernel, after sticking the above command into `/etc/rc.local` (minus the sudo part), and setting that file to `+x` so it gets run during boot. Only problem I have now is that I have to remap the windows/menu/whatever button on it to be "select/back" due to the HCI mappings, and some games in Steam just aren't working with a controller at all.